# JS templating: How do if/else upon value?

Tags: jquery, json, if-statement, mustache

**Given JSON data/css.json such:**

```
 { "CSS": [
 { "group":"Boxes", "css-class":"img",  "syntaxe": "img/css-metric.png",    "logic-english": "",    "level":"A1" }, 
 { "group":"Boxes", "css-class":"list", "syntaxe": "margin",    "logic-english": "",    "level":"A1" },
 { "group":"Boxes", "css-class":"list", "syntaxe": "margin-top",    "logic-english": "",    "level":"B2" },
 { "group":"Boxes", "css-class":"list", "syntaxe": "margin-right",  "logic-english": "",    "level":"B2" }
]}
```

**HTML such as:**

```
<body id="anchor"></body>
```

**HTML's JS such as:**

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/0.7.0/mustache.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script id="tpl" type="text/template">
    {{#CSS}}<div class="{{css-class}}"><p class="{{level}} level">{{syntaxe}}</p><p class="logic-english">{{logic-english}}</p></div>{{/CSS}}
</script>

<script>// Code 4: WORKS
        $(function() {
                $.getJSON('data/css.json', function(data) {
                    var template = $('#tpl').html();
                    var info = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
                    $('#anchor').html(info);
                });
        });
</script>
```

By editing the #tpl (I guess), **How to create a condition upon a value such as :**

if css-class's value == "img" then inject :

```
<img src="{{syntaxe}}" alt="An image" height="64" width="64">
```

else inject :

```
{{syntaxe}}
```

?

Comment: so wait, the incoming data looks like the JSON given there?

Comment: Yes. I think I copied it properly. If you see any typo mistake just notice me.

Comment: @j08691: may tou restore the title "**Mustache.js:** How do if/else upon value?". This question apply only to Mustache.js, it's important to let it appears in the title which is the first thing we see of any question.

Comment: FYI, updated my answer, you "might" find it useful. I hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>as suggested per previous answer comments</sub>

## Another Solution

<sub>Using jQuery's  methods on elements after they are created.</sub>

You can make use of jQuery's [Selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), and [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) methods to make the fixes after the templateing JavaScript has written the new elements to the DOM.

This would look something like:

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('data/css.json', function(data) {
        var template = $('#tpl').html();
        var info = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
        $('#anchor').html(info);

        $(".img").each(function(i) {
            var myP = $(this).children("p").first(),
                myClass = myP.attr("class"),
                mySrc = myP.text();
            myP.replaceWith($("<img />", { class: myClass, height: 64, width: 64, src: mySrc }));
        });
    });
});
```

jQuery References:

- [API](http://api.jquery.com/)
- [Selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
- [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)
- [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)
- [.first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/)
- [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) (also see [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/))
- [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)
- [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

Link to the [Mustache.js](http://mustache.github.io/) (i think he's using)

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Updated! Possible solution with "current" code at bottom</sub>

Try using jQuery's [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method:

```
if (data["CSS"]) {    //    check that CSS exist
    $.each(data.CSS, function(i, v) {  //  i is Index of the array, v is the Value
        if (v["css-class"]) {    //    check that the data value exist
            if (v["css-class"] == "img") {
                alert("TRUE");
            }
            else {
                alert("FALSE");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Again, I don't specifically know much of mustache, but If I take exactly what you have there, this is how I'd do it in jQuery specifically:

## jsFiddle Demo Here

```
$(function() {
        if (data["CSS"]) {    //    check that CSS exist
        $.each(data.CSS, function(i, v) {  //  i is Index of the array, v is the Value
            var newDiv = $("<div />", { class: v["css-class"] }).append(
                    $("<p />", { class: "logic-english", text: v["logic-english"] })
                );

            if (v["css-class"]) {    //    check that the data value exist
                if (v["css-class"] == "img") {
                    newDiv.prepend(
                        $("<img />", { class: v["level"], height: 64, width: 64, src: v["syntaxe"] })
                    );
                }
                else {
                    newDiv.prepend(
                        $("<p />", { class: v["level"], text: v["syntaxe"] })
                    );
                }
            }

            newDiv.appendTo($("#myContainer"));
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: Note: I found nothing on Mustache's manual, but I hope for a native mustache.js solution within the #tpl. However, thanks for this way to do it.

Comment: Honestly, don't know how my answer might help with use of "mustache" as I'm unfamiliar with any JS templating(i just dont see a point in it), but my answer will give you an easy "jQuery Mark-up" way to deal with iterating the data and making changes as needed.

Comment: @Hugolpz Added even more to my answer, something that "should" work even with your mustache templating

Comment: hiii... This last approach is unexpected but quite elegant.

Comment: please create a new answer with this last approach, so I can +1/valid it!

Comment: @Hugolpz I will when I get home

Comment: @Hugolpz Updated, and with one change. I changed `.prop("class")` to `.attr("class")`. Class is considered and "Attribute" not a "Property". Small mistake, but fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

The smallest modification I found to do something such if/then upon value **was to edit the JSON which now include both possible outcomes**. I added a JSON key `syntaxe2`. Both {syntaxe}'s value and {syntaxe2}'s value are called using `{{syntaxe}}{{{syntaxe2}}}`, but one and only one exists in a given row. Thus, it's either `{{syntaxe1}}` (escaped) **OR** `{{{syntaxe2}}}` (not escaped). This JSON+tpl trick have for my case the same effect as a if/then.

**(modified) JSON data/css.json such:**

```
 { "CSS": [
 { "group":"Boxes", "css-class":"img",  "syntaxe": "",  "syntaxe2": "<img src='img/css-metric.png' widht='100%' height='100%'>",    "logic-english": "",    "level":"A1" }, 
 { "group":"Boxes", "css-class":"list", "syntaxe": "margin",    "logic-english": "",    "level":"A1" },
 { "group":"Boxes", "css-class":"list", "syntaxe": "margin-top",    "logic-english": "",    "level":"B2" },
 { "group":"Boxes", "css-class":"list", "syntaxe": "margin-right",  "logic-english": "",    "level":"B2" }
]}
```

**(same) HTML such as:**

```
<body id="anchor"></body>
```

**(same) HTML's JS setting:**

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/0.7.0/mustache.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**(modified) HTML's JS template:**

```
<script id="tpl" type="text/template">
    {{#CSS}}<div class="{{css-class}}"><p class="{{level}} level">{{syntaxe}}{{{syntaxe}}}</p><p class="logic-english">{{logic-english}}</p></div>{{/CSS}}
</script>
```

**(same) HTML's JS injecter:**

```
<script>// Code 4: WORKS
        $(function() {
                $.getJSON('data/css.json', function(data) {
                    var template = $('#tpl').html();
                    var info = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
                    $('#anchor').html(info);
                });
        });
</script>
```